# In cocos2d (iphone) how would you animate a sprite (frame by frame)?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

What is the most efficient way to do this? I have four images that I would like to play to become an animated sprite. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Check out this [sample code](http://kwigbo.com/wp/2009/02/12/creating-an-animated-sprite-cocos2d-source-included/).

Comment: I did but for some reason I keep getting warnings.

Comment: What kind of warnings are you getting? I'm new to cocos2d but I can try to help. For me I simply double click SpriteTest.xcodeproj, click "build and run", and the project seems to work fine. I see "succeeded" in the bottom right and don't have any warnings.

Comment: There is also some more sample code under the "tests" directory in your cocos2d download. This is a little more complicated so I preferred the first link.

Comment: When I use his code I build with no warnings but when I try to add it to my project I get some warnings. Maybe I don't have all the frameworks added to my project?

Comment: I don't know why you're getting the warnings, but if you are correct then this tutorial will teach you how to add the necessary frameworks. http://monoclestudios.com/cocos2d_whitepaper.html

Comment: Your project should contain all the necessary frameworks to use that code. You implemented it wrong. Be specific about the error.

Answer (score -3):

How about:

```
UIImageView *imageView = …
imageView.animationImages = <array of images>
```

Comment: Well in cocos2d I'm using a Sprite.